# Extracting an array from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.x

I have data in the following format:

```
>>> print u.ravel()
[ array([[ -1.29376767e-01],
   [ -1.29525183e-01],
   [ -1.30267263e-01],
   [ -1.31603006e-01]])]
```

which is an array within a numpy array. I have tried `u[:]` but I cannot seem to call individual elements from the object.

Could anyone tell me how to extract data from object 'u'?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You just need to use `u[0]`.

Comment: what about `u.ravel()[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the looks of it, it apears `u.ravel()` returns an array with a numpy array in it. So maybe try

```
u.ravel()[0][:,:]
```

`[:,:]` because it is a two dimensional array